# Handle concurrent file download with flex/blazeDs/Spring

Tags: spring, flex3, scope, download, blazeds

I'm currently working on a Flex3/blazeDS/Spring/MySQL project.
In this, some users needs to download some import logs. Problem is that given the singleton concept around spring, if 2 users ask for a download at the same time, the servlet responsible for export file creation may cross content between the 2 asked files.
I'm not that much familiar with spring but from what i've been reading around it seems that the solution lies in saying that the servlet is in "Request" scope so there will be a new one created for each download request instead of having a singleton.
Does anyone have ever done something like this before? Every tutorials i've seen so far explains how to handle file download request but it never talks about the fact that 2 users asking for a download may have some issues...

Thanks for any leads on how to fix this.

Answer (score 0):

Each user will receive his own thread, and you should not have any problems unless using member variables (which is a bad practice anyway). If not, I do not see any problem, but it would help if you can post your code.